# Distribution that is invariant under R.V. Transformation

Tags: probability-theory, transformation

I came up with the following (small) problem and it seems to be quite difficult to solve...at least for me.

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be some unknown distribution. Find $\mathcal{P}$, such that $X \overset{iid}{\sim} \mathcal{P}$ and $\ln (aX^b) \overset{iid}{\sim} \mathcal{P}$, where $a>0$ and $b\neq 0$.

Although I am interested in this specific case, I am generally interested in how you would solve such a problem.

For transformations of continuous random variables, I referenced the paper [here](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Ejwatkins/f-transform.pdf) (page 2). Using the equation:

\begin{equation}
 f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y))\left| \frac{d}{dy} g^{-1}(y)\right|
\end{equation}

we would have to solve something like

\begin{equation}
f(y) = \frac{b}{y} f(\ln(y))
\end{equation}

where $f$ is the functional form of the distribution we seek.

I have tried to solve this several ways but I am not getting very far and so I am turning to this community to see if I have missed something or there is some technique I am not currently aware of. Any insights are greatly appreciated!